# Text in GridView is aligned to center only in the first item

Tags: android, gridview, textview, centering

I have a `GridView` with `BaseAdapter` attached to it in my Android app. In every cell of the `GridView` I have a `CardView` with an image and 2 TextViews in it. The problem is that the items of every cell should be aligned to `center_vertical`, but only the first item of the `GridView` is aligned to `center_vertical`.

cellLayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/itemImageList"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top|center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/itemNameList"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/itemPriceList"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom|center_vertical"/>

    </GridLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In the GridView there are 3 columns, so only the left item in the first row is aligned properly. The texts in the rest of the cells are aligned to the left.

How can I fix this so all texts will be aligned to `center_vertical`?

Comment: You do not need GridLayout inside your cardview. Use a relative layout inside your cardview and align your TextView and ImageViews

Comment: If you're using GridLayout, you need to set rowSpec and columnSpec, and use setGravity method to specify a child's alignment within its cell group. Read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html